# Small confusing regarding the elements of powersets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am a bit confused with something very elementary, there is this from Mazzola/Milmeister/Weissman's book: *Comprehensive Mathematics for Computer Scientists.*

> [image]

And then there is this lemma:

> [image]

If $a\subset a$, does it follow that $\{a\} \in 2^a$? Shouldn't it be $a\in 2^a$ or $\{a\}\subset 2^a$?

Consider the example 3 given earlier, $\{c\}$ is not an element of $2^a$ but $c$ is. I may be reading something wrong.

Comment: $\{a\}$ isn't a subset of $a$ because $a\in a$ is prohibited, right? So $a\in 2^a$ is better. But that doesn't stand in contradiction with $2^{\{a,b\}}=\{\emptyset,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$. Notice a difference between $2^X$ and $2^{\{X\}}$

Comment: Wow they're appealing to the powerset axiom for the existence of a singleton. I think I hear Jack Silver rolling over in his grave.

Comment: @blargoner I guess this happens because they use the [axiom of equality instead of the axiom of extensionality](https://i.imgur.com/afqUhaB.png).

Comment: No, my point is that the powerset axiom is overkill here. Their axiom 4 (pairing) already gives the existence of $\{a\}$, and then also $\{a,\{a\}\}$. Their axiom 3 (union) then gives $\bigcup\{a,\{a\}\}$, which is $a^+$. It's notable but perhaps not surprising for computer science that they're omitting the axiom of foundation / regularity (cc @FShrike @X-Rui).

Comment: @blargoner But we would need to prove that $\{a,a\}=\{a\}$, no? We can create the first one with the axiom of pairing, but I've been thinking on how to prove they are the same and couldn't do it.

Comment: I just read your textbook and wow it has some subtle differences from the usual ZFC axioms I've learnt. The axiom of extensionality is the same as Definition 1 (equality of sets) together with Axiom 2 (Axiom of Equality) in your textbook. I'll edit my answer to include a proof of $\{a, a\} = \{a\}$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I believe you are right; it seems an error of the original text. Because $a$ is a subset of itself, it is an element of its power set, i.e. $a \in 2^a$. As user FShrike commented, the line $\{a\} \in 2^a$ in the original text, implying $a \in a$, is forbidden by the axiom of regularity.

It is not clear what the original text actually was meant to say: just replacing $\{a\} \in 2^a$ by either $a \in 2^a$ or $\{a\} \subseteq 2^a$ does not yield a complete proof for the existence of $\{a\}$. The proof I was taught was by the axiom of pairing: you pair $a$ with itself into a set, giving $\{a, a\} = \{a\}$. Or, if you really want to use power sets, maybe you can use the axiom (schema) of specification on $2^a$. That is, $\{x \in 2^a\ |\ x = a\} = \{a\}$.

In response to why $\{a, a\} = \{a\}$, asked in the comments of the question, here's an answer. Fundamentally, $\{a\}$ is some symbols that try to represent a set by saying it contains exactly $a$ as an element. $\{a, a\}$ represents the same thing: its elements are either $a$ or $a$, which is to say its elements are exactly $a$. This set may not exist, or not be unique, in which case it would be called not well-defined. However, if a set with that property does exist, it must be unique, either by the axiom of extensionality, or by the definition of equality of sets. And, such a set can be given by the pair of $a$ and $a$ itself, showing its existence. Thus, $\{a\}$ and $\{a, a\}$ both represent the unique set that contains exactly $a$ as an element.

Comment: I believe they meant $2^{2^a}$ which in their notation is P(P(a)) which does contain {a}

Comment: @MichaelCarey I was thinking that too! But now I am thinking, by definition, the elements of $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(a))$ are the subsets of $\mathcal{P}(a)$. So before knowing $\{a\}$ is a set, we cannot say it is a subset of $\mathcal{P}(a)$, and we don't know $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(a))$ contains $\{a\}$ as an element, right?

Comment: You are right. I really can't make heads or tails of this books introduction on the axioms

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment:

After taking a closer look at the first few chapters of the book, I'm not even confident their logical foundations are coherent. There's lots of weird stuff going on: not correctly distinguishing names from objects named (i.e. use/mention errors everywhere), not distinguishing sentences from propositions expressed, stuff about "concepts" and "instances" which is either undefined or insufficiently explained.

Regarding the question of whether $\{a,a\}=\{a\}$ for example, one first needs to understand what the notation on the page even means. Here $a$ denotess a given set. According to the authors notational conventions, something like $P=\{a,a\}$ is shorthand for the bizarre "instantiation" via "selection" of the set "concept" $P@\textrm{Set}(a,a)$, while $S=\{a\}$ is shorthand for $S@\textrm{Set}(a)$. The question is then whether $P=S$. But does "=" here mean identity or equality, which the authors distinguish but do not explain? If it's equality, then $P=S$ follows from their definition of equality. If it's identity, then we need to look at what they say about identity of instances of concepts constructed via selection, namely:

> The value of an instance of a concept constructed as a selection is the collection of the references to selected instances of the component.

Aside from concepts, instances, values, etc., what's a "collection" here? What's a "reference"? What are the rules for these things? God only knows. These are essentially the only occurrences of those words in the book.

Unfortunately these foundational issues seem to create confusion about basic things. In their first example about sets they say of $A=\{a,b,\{c,d\}\}$ that $c\not\in A$, even though they provide no information about the relationships between $a,b,c,d$. Are they identifying sets with  names for sets? Are they assuming that a set can't have two different names, or can't be equal to a set with a different name? None of this is clear. Earlier in the book they say:

> ...if two concepts have identical names, then they have identical construction principles and identical components. The same holds for instances: identicals name mean identical concepts and identical values.

Huh?

Personally I wouldn't look to this book for solid foundations.